# foreach with get() return only one record laravel?

Tags: laravel

i want to sum profit by activating multiple plans. I am using `get()` with `foreach` but it returns only last row data. not all rows data.  its strange while on other queries it returns all rows data.
 for example, I have 2 deposits one 25$ and 2nd 35$ its returns 35$ data only.
i tried with

```
 $deposits = Deposit::get();
```

but it is not working I went to increase rows to 12 but still, it returns data of 12th row only

```
 $deposits = Deposit::where('account_id', $account->id)->where('status',1)->get();

                  foreach($deposits as $pn) {

                       $plans = package::where('id',$pn->plan)->first();
                       $percent = $plans->min_amount * $plans->percent/100;

                  }
```

Comment: Are you sure there are multiple rows that match  these 2 conditions? `where('account_id', $account->id)->where('status',1)`

Comment: yes .. both are there

Comment: @Sehdev its returns only last row . for example i have 2 deposits one of 25$ and 2nd 35$ its returns 35$ data only

Comment: To be sure, provide the data from your database.

Comment: yes data is provided thats why its returning for one right ?  i added 12 rows again to test but returns only last

Comment: @cryptohacks I mean, add to your question.

Comment: Can you `dd( $deposits)` before `foreach`? What the result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210099/discussion-between-crypto-hacks-and-wahyu-kristianto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing in chat, the real problem is adding up the percentages during looping :

```
$percent = 0;

foreach ($deposited as $de) {
    $pack    = Package::Where('id', $de->plan)->first();
    $log     = Deposit::Where('id', $de->id)->first();
    $percent = $percent + ($log->amount * $pack->percent / 100);
}
```